# How to update AutoHotkey GUI Text control?

Tags: user-interface, autohotkey

I am trying to display and update a gui element (text string). Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here? The initial text is never replaced by the updating text in the loop.

```
kills=0

#n::
Gui,Add,Text,vStatus, starting the killing
Gui,Show,w250 h375
Loop
{
GuiControl,,vStatus, killed %kills% Glorks!
kills+=1
Sleep,3000
}
return
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is working code:

```
kills=0

#n::
    Gui,Add,Text,vStatus, starting the killing
    Gui,Show,w250 h375, Glorks counter
    Loop
    {
        IfWinNotExist, Glorks counter
        {
            Gui, Destroy
            return
        }
        GuiControl,,Status, killed %kills% Glorks!
        kills+=1
        Sleep,3000
    }
return
```

Your mistakes:

1. You should use `Status` instead of `vStatus` in `GuiControl` command.
2. When you close GUI, you are not stopping loop, so `IfWinNotExist` detect if window exists and if not exists it will destroy all gui variables and exit from loop. So you can again press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> and start gui again.

Note:
If you want to start count kills every time from `0` when gui is started then move `kills=0` to right after `#n::`

Comment: A note if you stumble across this solution and have 2 gui s (with windowhandle A and B).   To set the GuiControl of a certain gui it is "GuiControl,A: ,Status, killed %kills% Glorks!"